# Select empty weeks in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am grouping by weeks using DATEPART in SQL.  However, I want to include the empty weeks also, not only weeks that include values.  I have a script that works perfectly collecting data by weeks, but not the empty weeks.  I´ve been trying to use left outer join but my SQL skills are not all that great.  I decided to ask you guys.

Here is my script:

```
select 
    DatePart(Year, MYTABLE.CREATION_DATE) as DateYear,
    DatePart(Month, MYTABLE.CREATION_DATE) as DateMonth,
    DatePart(Week, MYTABLE.CREATION_DATE) as DateWeek,
    sum(cast(MYTABLE.BASE_TRANSACTION_VALUE as int)) as Value,
    min(MYTABLE.CREATION_DATE) as DateT
from MYTABLE
where MYTABLE.SEGMENT2 like '00601'
    and MYTABLE.SEGMENT4 like '%'
    and MYTABLE.CREATION_DATE > '2012-12-30 12:00:00'
    and MYTABLE.CREATION_DATE < '2013-12-30 11:00:00'
group by 
    DatePart(Year, MYTABLE.CREATION_DATE), 
    DatePart(Month, MYTABLE.CREATION_DATE), 
    DatePart(Week, MYTABLE.CREATION_DATE)
order by DateYear, DateMonth, DateWeek
```

**And this is the result of that script.**

[image]

**Could you guys possibly give me an example of a join clause could look like in this case?**

Comment: You need a table with 52 numbers.

Comment: please give some table data example

Comment: @Melon What's wrong with the image OP posted?

Comment: Well, imgur is blocked for some people...

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO absolutly nothing, just that img is the output of his script, and im asking for the uncut table data.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I just thought Melon was blind.

Comment: i think my vision still working xD, sorry for the confusion! at this hour of the afternoon is not easy to concentrate

Comment: Sorry about that guys, I´ll try to edit my question and add a record from MyTable.  The thing is, a single record has quite many columns so perhaps it would look like garbage.  I´ll figure out how to paste it here.

Comment: @gardarvalur crate a live example here: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/ and in addition we could test our responses before posting here !! everybody win!

Comment: I want to thank all of you, this is working with @BrettSchneider answer  :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do it. My SQLFiddle is http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b777f/1/0

```
declare @WeekTable table(
    [WeekDate] datetime
)
declare @startDate datetime,
@EndDate datetime
select @startDate = '1/1/2013',@EndDate = '12/31/2013'
while @startDate<=@EndDate begin
    insert into @WeekTable values(@startDate)
    set @startDate = @startDate+7
end

select 
    DatePart(Year, [WeekDate]) as DateYear,
    DatePart(Month, [WeekDate]) as DateMonth,
    DatePart(Week, [WeekDate]) as DateWeek,
    sum(cast(MYTABLE.BASE_TRANSACTION_VALUE as int)) as Value,
    min(isnull(MYTABLE.CREATION_DATE,[WeekDate])) as DateT
from
    @WeekTable
    left outer join
    MYTABLE
    on 
    DatePart(Week,MYTABLE.CREATION_DATE) =DatePart(Week, [WeekDate])
    and
    DatePart(Year,MYTABLE.CREATION_DATE) =DatePart(Year, [WeekDate])
    and
    MYTABLE.SEGMENT2 like '00601'
    and
    MYTABLE.SEGMENT4 like '%'
group by 
    DatePart(Year, [WeekDate]) , 
    DatePart(Month, [WeekDate]), 
    DatePart(Week, [WeekDate])
order by
    DateYear, DateMonth, DateWeek
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer @KyleUp, however for some reason all the Values are always null.

Comment: @gardarvalur the values that are null are all empty weeks. You could change the Value column to `isnull(sum(cast(MYTABLE.BASE_TRANSACTION_VALUE as int)),0) as Value ` to make it zeros rather than nulls.

Comment: I actually went for the other answer, it worked like a charm.  But I´m going to up you for your effort, thanks for your help  :)

Comment: No problem. @BrettSchneider still has a problem in the query for any week that overlaps 2 months. For instance and a date 1/28-1/31 is in week 5, month 1. He's joining on month AND week. So week 5 is only in month 2. Only 2/1 - 2/3 would be included in the result. This issue affects any week spanning with multiple months.

Comment: Hmm... I did not notice that @KyleUp, so you're telling me that I should only join on week?

Comment: Another question, when I run your script it will always return 0 in Value for each week. Can you spot out why?  (I would really like to use your script but can´t find out why it doesn´t sum my values).

Comment: Yes, just join on week. You can add in year too if you want to be sure weeks from different years don't get squished together. I looked at my join and there I wasn't joining the date together correctly. It should be okay now.

Comment: Thank you @KyleUp, your solution works correctly now.  I think I´m going to use your solution now  :)

Answer (score 6):

[updated 2014-01-09 08:06 UTC]

you can create the dates dynamically (DateRange) and the outer-join them to your select like this:

```
declare @startdate date;
set @startdate = '2012-12-30';
declare @enddate date;
set @enddate = '2013-12-30'

;with DateRange AS
(
    SELECT 
        DatePart(Year, @startdate) as DateYear,
        DatePart(Month, @startdate) as DateMonth,
        DatePart(iso_Week, @startdate) as DateWeek,
        @startdate as DateValue
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        DatePart(Year, dateadd(dd,7,DateValue)) as DateYear,
        DatePart(Month, dateadd(dd,7,DateValue)) as DateMonth,
        DatePart(iso_Week, dateadd(dd,7,DateValue)) as DateWeek,
        dateadd(dd,7,DateValue)
    FROM   DateRange
    WHERE  dateadd(dd,7,DateValue) <= @enddate
), data as (
    select 
        DatePart(Year, MYTABLE.CREATION_DATE) as DateYear,
        DatePart(Month, MYTABLE.CREATION_DATE) as DateMonth,
        DatePart(iso_Week, MYTABLE.CREATION_DATE) as DateWeek,
        sum(cast(MYTABLE.BASE_TRANSACTION_VALUE as int)) as Value,
        min(MYTABLE.CREATION_DATE) as DateT
    from MYTABLE
    where MYTABLE.SEGMENT2 like '00601'
        and MYTABLE.SEGMENT4 like '%'
        and MYTABLE.CREATION_DATE > '2012-12-30 12:00:00'
        and MYTABLE.CREATION_DATE < '2013-12-30 11:00:00'
    group by 
        DatePart(Year, MYTABLE.CREATION_DATE),
        DatePart(Month, MYTABLE.CREATION_DATE),
        DatePart(iso_Week, MYTABLE.CREATION_DATE)
)
select 
    DateRange.DateYear,
    DateRange.DateMonth,
    DateRange.DateWeek,
    data.Value,
    data.DateT
from data
right outer join
DateRange 
on 
    data.DateYear = DateRange.DateYear
and data.DateWeek = DateRange.DateWeek
order by 
    DateRange.DateYear, 
    DateRange.DateMonth, 
    DateRange.DateWeek
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer @BrettSchneider but for some reason the empty records are not fetched into the dataset.  Only the same records as before.

Comment: if you are looking for week 01 in 2013, sql server splits the week in half (hence week 53) and calls the first few days of the new year week 1. since both weeks are 7 days in total, either 53 or 1 is skipped when moving one week forward. i changed the code to use iso_week where each week is seven days long

Comment: You are using a where clause and it's negating the outer join so you'll only get results for the weeks you have data.
Additionally if you join on month and week, some weeks span multiple months so you'd end up filtering out hits.

Comment: @KevinUp: thanks you! i changed the code such that the where is encapsuled and the join made later

Comment: Haha!  That did the trick @BrettSchneider!  This is working perfectly now, thank you guys, all of you  :)